First option is always null in InputSelect
In my Blazor app, the <InputSelect /> component is not working as expected.  The first option is being shown as selected, but when I submit the form it is always null.
Relevant Model properties:
public int? Distance { get; set; }
public Dictionary<int, string> DistanceList { get; set; }

//Set in the constructor
DistanceList = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 5, "5 Miles" },
    { 10, "10 Miles" },
    { 25, "25 Miles" }
};

Select List:
<InputSelect @bind-Value="model.Distance">
    @foreach (var distance in model.DistanceList)
    {
        <option value=@distance.Key>@distance.Value</option>                                                            
    }
</InputSelect>

If I select "10 Miles" or "25 Miles" first, then select "5 miles", then submit the form, Distance will be 5 miles.  But if I just submit the form, Distance is null.  Even though, 5 miles is selected.

Probably because your Distance is not set yet. So your Distance is null, but UI displays options that you populated and it doesn't have nullable option to match Distance to it. So it displays incorrectly.
You can fix it the next way:
<InputSelect @bind-Value="model.Distance">
    @foreach (var distance in model.DistanceList)
    {
        @if (model.Distance == null)
        {
            model.Distance = @distance.Key;
        }
        <option value=@distance.Key>@distance.Value</option>                                                            
    }
</InputSelect>

It will help you to avoid creating an empty option and will allow to set the first value in the DistanceList as selected.

The problem is that null is not a option in the list, so the select displays the list but nothing is actually selected.
Either set Distance as not nullable with a default valid value, or do something like this:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="Distance">
    @if (Distance is null)
    {
        <option selected disabled value="null"> -- Select A Value -- </option>
    }
    @foreach (var distance in DistanceList)
    {
        <option value=@distance.Key>@distance.Value</option>
    }
</InputSelect>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Distance : @Distance</pre>
</div>

@code {
    public int? Distance { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, string> DistanceList = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        { 5, "5 Miles" },
        { 10, "10 Miles" },
        { 25, "25 Miles" }
    };
}

Which will look like this:


I need a way to fix this while still keeping my desired functionality.  I don’t want to display a “Select a value” option.

If you don’t want to display a “Select a value” you need to set the model value in the form to a default form option when Distance is null?  What's that default?
